# When to use Delimiter or Split in Java?

Tags: java, split, delimiter

So I have some code that reads through a text file and a new item is recognized by when a new line is made in the text file. How would this code change if I decided to use a delimiter instead of split? I am new to java and am not sure when to use which.

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(DESTINATIONS_FILE)))
        {
            destinations = new ArrayList<>();
            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] newDestination = scanner.nextLine().split("\n");
                destinations.add(newDestination[0]);

            }

        }
```

Comment: In place of \n use the delimiter of your choice

Comment: FYI: `scanner.nextLine()` already splits the input at new lines, so you don't need to do `.split("\n")`.  That said, the choice of recognizing items by either a new line or by a delimiter _other than_ a new line depends entirely on how the items had originally been written to the text file. You need to know (or else be able to figure out) what the format of the data in the text file is before you can decide how to read it.